# Android studio is not giving suggestion when I'm using relative layout

Tags: android, android-studio

#### My problem:

I'm not getting suggestion in `xml` file of android studio while working on relative layout. 0 suggestions are available, if I press `control+space`.

#### What I have tried?

I tried to solve this by deleting `.idea` folder and `.ime` folder, but still it is not working I'm getting 0 suggestions, but suggestions are available in Java file and on constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try Invalidate Cache/Restart. If nothing changes then try to restart your computer. Keep the Internet Connection On and then Launch Android Studio. 
I think the problem is not with Layout.